# what could possibly be the reason that my application suddenly lose connection to mongodb and unable to reconnect

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, microservices

I'm building mircroservices architecture and deploy my applications on kubernetes.
There's one of my application which is regularly lose the connection to mongodb and it's unable to reconnect. The other applications that connected to the same mongodb still work just fine except this one. I don't really know why so I restarted the deployment and it works just fine for a few days. What could probably be the reason. Is there a way to diagnose. This is the repeated log that shows on my server.

```
  {"timestamp":"2023-07-12 11:33:55.565","level":"ERROR","thread":"nioEventLoopGroup-4-1","logger":"reactor.core.publisher.Operators","message":"Operator called default onErrorDropped","context":"default","exception":"reactor.core.Exceptions$ErrorCallbackNotImplemented: com.mongodb.MongoConnectionPoolClearedException: Connection pool for ServerId{clusterId=ClusterId{value='64ae6919a9e2c43a81450e15', description='null'}, address=mysecretdbserver:27017} is paused because another operation failed
    Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoConnectionPoolClearedException: Connection pool for ServerId{clusterId=ClusterId{value='64ae6919a9e2c43a81450e15', description='null'}, address=mysecretdbserver:27017} is paused because another operation failed
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$StateAndGeneration.throwIfClosedOrPaused(DefaultConnectionPool.java:1554)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.getAsync(DefaultConnectionPool.java:204)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer.getConnectionAsync(DefaultServer.java:122)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.binding.AsyncClusterBinding$AsyncClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(AsyncClusterBinding.java:201)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.async.client.ClientSessionBinding$SessionBindingAsyncConnectionSource.getConnection(ClientSessionBinding.java:214)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor.getMore(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:240)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor.next(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:188)
    \tat com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.BatchCursor.lambda$next$0(BatchCursor.java:35)
    \tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate.subscribe(MonoCreate.java:58)
    \tat reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4455)
    \tat reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribeWith(Mono.java:4570)
    \tat reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4283)
    \tat com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.BatchCursorFlux.recurseCursor(BatchCursorFlux.java:104)
    \tat com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.BatchCursorFlux.lambda$recurseCursor$4(BatchCursorFlux.java:101)
    \tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:171)
    \tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal$MonoTerminalPeekSubscriber.onNext(MonoPeekTerminal.java:180)
    \tat reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:854)
    \tat reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:172)
    \tat com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.MongoOperationPublisher.lambda$sinkToCallback$30(MongoOperationPublisher.java:549)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor.handleGetMoreQueryResult(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:387)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor.access$700(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:64)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor$CommandResultSingleResultCallback.onResult(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:422)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.operation.AsyncQueryBatchCursor$CommandResultSingleResultCallback.onResult(AsyncQueryBatchCursor.java:397)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServer$DefaultServerProtocolExecutor$2.onResult(DefaultServer.java:276)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandProtocolImpl$1.onResult(CommandProtocolImpl.java:84)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection$1.onResult(DefaultConnectionPool.java:684)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection$2.onResult(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:159)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.async.ErrorHandlingResultCallback.onResult(ErrorHandlingResultCallback.java:48)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:521)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$2$1.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:498)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:821)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback$MessageCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:785)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:645)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:642)
    \tat com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.readAsync(NettyStream.java:319)
    \tat com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.readAsync(NettyStream.java:266)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.readAsync(InternalStreamConnection.java:642)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.access$600(InternalStreamConnection.java:86)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:775)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$MessageHeaderCallback.onResult(InternalStreamConnection.java:760)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:645)
    \tat com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection$5.completed(InternalStreamConnection.java:642)
    \tat com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.readAsync(NettyStream.java:319)
    \tat com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.handleReadResponse(NettyStream.java:347)
    \tat com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream.access$1100(NettyStream.java:105)
    \tat com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$InboundBufferHandler.channelRead0(NettyStream.java:421)
    \tat com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$InboundBufferHandler.channelRead0(NettyStream.java:418)
    \tat io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    \tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    \tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    \tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    \tat io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    \tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    \tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    \tat io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    \tat io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    \tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    \tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    \tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    \tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    \tat io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    \tat io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    \tat io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    \tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message
    \tat com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$InboundBufferHandler.exceptionCaught(NettyStream.java:427)
    \tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:346)
    \tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:325)
    \tat io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:317)
    \tat com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStream$ReadTimeoutTask.run(NettyStream.java:564)
    \tat io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98)
    \tat io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:153)
    \tat io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    \tat io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    \tat io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    \tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    \t... 4 common frames omitted
    Caused by: io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException: null
    "}
    {"timestamp":"2023-07-12 11:33:55.566","level":"INFO","thread":"reactor-http-epoll-3","logger":"org.mongodb.driver.cluster","message":"No server chosen by com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.ClientSessionHelper$$Lambda$4095/0x0000000801b47c98@2753cbae from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=mysecretdbserver:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message}, caused by {io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException}}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out","context":"default"}
```